# How to override '-webkit-appearance'

Tags: css

I have the following CSS which is injected by JavaScript:

```css
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

If I open up Chrome developer tools and uncheck those properties things look OK. How would I override this property in the CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The **appearance** property is used to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's theme."

Here are some options available:

- button
- button-bevel
- caret
- checkbox
- default-button
- listbox
- listitem
- media-fullscreen-button
- media-mute-button
- media-play-button
- media-seek-back-button
- media-seek-forward-button
- media-slider
- media-sliderthumb
- menulist
- menulist-button
- menulist-text
- menulist-textfield
- none
- push-button
- radio
- searchfield
- searchfield-cancel-button
- searchfield-decoration
- searchfield-results-button
- searchfield-results-decoration
- slider-horizontal
- slider-vertical
- sliderthumb-horizontal
- sliderthumb-vertical
- square-button
- textarea
- textfield

For more look at mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

or

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp

This is a CSS3 protery so you should be aware of the comparability:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHg9.png

Answer (score 6):

Maverick's answer is correct, but to be specific, I found the following put the scroll bar back on a select item:

```
select{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist
}
```

Comment: here an improvement: -webkit-appearance: menulist ;
   -moz-appearance:    menulist ;
   appearance:       menulist ;